# Problems to create a unit test for http.post

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

I created this class to use http.post in dart:

```
class SigninDataSource {
  final http.Client client;

  SigninDataSource(this.client);

  Future<SignIn> signIn ({
    String email = 'test@hotmail.com',
    String password = 'test',
  }) async {
    var url = "https://test/test/signin";
    var body = json.decode('{"email": "$email", "password": "$password"}');

    final result = await client.post(url, body: json.encode(body), headers: {"content-type": "application/json",});
    print("Result");
    print(result);

    if(result.statusCode == 200) {
      SignIn.fromJson((result.body));
      return SignIn.fromJson(result.body);
    } else {
      throw SignInError(json.decode(result.body)['message']);
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to create a unit test for it.

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  String fixture(String name) => File('test/data/fixtures/$name.json').readAsStringSync();

  MockClient mockClient;
  SigninDataSource dataResource;

  setUp((){
    mockClient = MockClient();
    dataResource = SigninDataSource(mockClient);
  });

  group('signin', () {
    test(
      'return SignIn whrn the service call complete succesfully',
        () async {
          when(
            mockClient.post(
              "https://test/test/signin",
              body: '{"email": "test@test.com", "password": "Test@123"}',
              headers: {"content-type": "application/json"}
            )).thenAnswer(
              (_) async => http.Response('{"status": 200}', 200));
          expect(await dataResource.signIn(email: 'test@test.com', password:'Test@123'),TypeMatcher<SignIn>());
        }
    );
  });
}
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Result
null

NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'statusCode' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: statusCode
```

I think my mock method is not working but I cannot figure out what is the problem. I was checkoing this documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking I tried to replicate it for a http.post.Please, could someone with more experience help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `body` parameter `{"email": "test@test.com", "password": "Test@123"}` in `mockClient.post()` during stubbing does not match the one being passed in `client.post()` in `SigninDataSource`.

If you check the string being passed in `client.post()`

From

```dart
final result = await client.post(url, body: json.encode(body), headers: {
  "content-type": "application/json",
});
```

to

```dart
var encodedBody = json.encode(body);

final result = await client.post(url, body: encodedBody, headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
});
```

The value of `encodedBody` is `{"email":"test@test.com","password":"Test@123"}`. Notice that there are no spaces.

You can also modify your stubbing to this if you want to disregard the value of the parameters being passed since you only need the success response. You will use `anyNamed('paramName')`.

```dart
when(mockClient.post("https://test/test/signin",
        body: anyNamed('body'),
        headers: anyNamed('headers')))
    .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"status": 200}', 200));
```